# Netty support for Google's QUIC protocol

Tags: netty

Is there a plan to support google's QUIC protocol in netty? (http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/88/slides/slides-88-tsvarea-10.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

It's an opensource project, we love contributions. So if someone will write the implementation we are happy to review and check ;)